# Posting variables with AJAX to a php function on a different file and calling the function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to post variables via `AJAX` and using these variables to run a script that creates a list of `checkbox` options.  My code is as follows:

```
*index.php*



 require_once ("session_start.php");
    require_once ("ajax.php");
    error_reporting ( E_ALL );
    ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );
    $link = mysqli_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', '' );

    if (! $link) {
        die ( "Connection failed" . mysqli_errno ( $link ) );
    }
function getDBlist() {
            global $link;
            $qry = ("SHOW DATABASES");
            $res = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $res ) ) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="db"  value="' . $row ['Database'] . '" class="checkbox" />';
                echo $row ['Database'];
            }
        }
        getDBlist ();
```

*The Script*

```
$(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function () {
    var db = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {"db=" + db},
        success: function (html) {
            $("#qryDisplay").show();
        }
    });
});
```

ajax.php

```
function showTables() {
    if (isset ( $_POST ['db'] )) {
        $db = $_POST ['db'];
        $link = mysqli_connect ( '192.168.2.113', 'root', '', $db );
        $qry = "SHOW tables";
        $tbl_list = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
        ?>
<ul>
         <?php
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $tbl_list ) ) {
            ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tbl[]" class="tbl_list"
        value="<?php echo   $row [0];   ?>" />
            <?php echo $row [0]; ?>
            <br>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
showTables ();
?>
</ul>
<?php
function tblProperties() {
    if (isset ( $_POST ['tbl'] )) {
        $tbl = $_POST ['tbl'];
        $db = $_POST ['db'];
        $link = mysqli_connect ( '192.168.2.113', 'root', '', $db );
        $qry = "DESCRIBE $tbl";
        $result = mysqli_query ( $link, $qry );
        ?>
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Heading">
        <div class="Cell2">
            <p> <?php echo $tbl; ?> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div id="topRow">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tbl" id="tblall" value="All" />
            <p>ALL</p>
        </div>
        <?php
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $result ) ) {
            ?>
            <div class="draggable-cell ui-widget-content">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tbl" class="tblst"
                value="<?php echo $row[0];?>" />
            <p><?php echo $row[0]; ?> </p>
        </div>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
</div>
<?php } } tblProperties();
```

(Clicking the checkbox should post a variable db to my ajax.php page)
At this point I believe i'm doing everything right, however when I call the `ajax.php` functions like `showtables()` in my `index.php` file I get no results. Could it be that the variables aren't being posted? If so why would the success condition be fulfilled? Have I missed something crucial?

Comment: Can you show your console result when this action triggers ?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in the `error_log` file

Comment: Not in error log, your browser's consol, click on `All` and make this request again so consol will show you a string and when you will click on that string you can see `POST` and `request`. Show me that result

Comment: The table with the `All` checkbox is the last table to be generated, that table is generated after an option is selected from the `tbl_list`. The problem I am having is that I can't generate the `tbl_list` when I choose an option from my db `checkbox`. Its a bit confusing but I hope you can follow.

Comment: I understood that, What I asked is press `F12` in your **web browser**, then go to `console` tab and make a request by clicking on checkbox, so you can see the generated request in `console`. Now click on that request in console and it will show you `POST` and `response`,show me whatever value that contains. Got it?

Comment: Understood, I just tried that like you suggested. when I clicked my `checkbox` option there was nothing in the `console`.

Comment: Try same in `net` panel if your are firefox or in `Network` panel if you are using chrome. Because it will show something like this there `localhost/yourproject/ajax.php` if your ajax request is actually trigerring. If it does not shows, your javascript has some problem in making ajax request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73926/discussion-between-noobatnerd-and-aryan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace below:

```
data: {"db=" + db},
```

With below and try:

```
data: {db: db},
```

Comment: Tried this to no avail.

Comment: You also need to replace `$("#qryDisplay").show();` with  `$("#qryDisplay").html(html).show();` to add the result and make sure `ip` `192.168.2.113` is correct or use `localhost`

Comment: `$("#qryDisplay").show();` is not the problem that was just a test to see if the variables were being posted. The problem lies which my php function not executing and creating my checkbox list.

Comment: It's working fine for me, only issues I can think of either jquery reference is not added or database user/password/host is not correct

Comment: So when you click the preloaded checkbox it displays the second checkbox?

Comment: Yes, example for `information_schema` `table` result is: `<ul>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="tbl[]" class="tbl_list"
        value="columns_priv" />` etc...

Comment: Okay so I have confirmed that the `ajax.php` functions are executing and I have also checked the results are being sent back via the web `console`. But why can't I print these results when I call the message in my `index.php` file? Why aren't the checkbox being generated??

Comment: I have already posted in above comment you need to set the html `$("#qryDisplay").html(html).show();` code `$("#qryDisplay").html(html)` is to generate checkbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73940/discussion-between-noobatnerd-and-manoj-yadav).

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo your result set in ajax.php. you did not echo any thing or did not return anything.

Comment: I echoed the results inside the input tag  `<input type="checkbox" name="tbl[]" class="tbl_list"
        value="<?php echo   $row [0];   ?>" />`

Comment: Did you echo the whole result in ajax.php which you want back into your main page?? like $res = yourfunc(); echo $res;

Comment: I tried this but i'm not sure I understand what you mean, If I do `$res = showTables (); echo $res;`, and in my `index.php` I am also calling `showTables();` what does this really achieve?